# 1d Smart Pointer doesn't work with syntax (*)++

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019, smart-pointers

I am learning about smart-pointer. So, I have arrowed code which I don't understand. code shown below. I tried below code in visual studio 2019.
why can't i use increment operator (*i)++ where as i can use i[0]++.

```
shared_ptr<int[]> foo(shared_ptr<int[]>i)
{
    cout << i << '\n';
    (*i)++;             // doesn't        but works for shared_ptr<int>i as argument
    i[0]++;            //  works             
    *i += 1;          // <--  doesn't  work
    i[0] += 1;        // <--- works 
    return i;
}

int main(int argc)
{
  
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   // int T;
    //cin >> T;
   // while (T--)
  //  {
        std::unique_ptr<int[]> pointer(new int[5]);                 // <-- can  do it 
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) pointer[i] = i;

        auto pointer3 = make_unique<int[] >(new int[5]);  // <--- can't do it Okay i know that there is no overload but what's reason for not having ?
        cout << pointer << '\n';
        auto pointer1 = std::move(pointer);
        cout << pointer1 << '\n';
        auto shrd_ptr = foo(std::move(pointer1));
        cout << shrd_ptr << '\n';
  //  }
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end -start).count() <<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

**ERROR List :**

> ```
>     Error C2088   '++': illegal for class 
>     Error C2100   illegal indirection 
>     Error (active)    E0349   no operator "*" matches these operands  
>     Error (active)    E0349   no operator "*" matches these operands  
>     Error (active)    E0042   no instance of overloaded fucntion "make_unique" matches the argument list
> ```

Comment: That's because the smart pointer is a pointer to an *array*, and with e.g. `(*i)++` you attempt to change where the array starts. It's basically the same as doing `int arr[10]; arr++;`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Exaclty i am trying to change first element of arr. what do you think what should i use to change first element i mean should i use such syntax(**i)++? will it work ?

Comment: Why not just treat the smart pointer as an array, and use `i[0]++`? Or better yet use `std::vector` or `std::array`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am sorry but then what's the point of smart pointer if we can not use as a pointer? i know we can use std::vetcor and std::array. i am trying to understanding smart pointer in depth.

Comment: My recommendation is that you look at the smart pointer not as self-deleting pointers, but in terms of *ownership*. Should a resource have only one owner at a time? Use `std::unique_ptr`. Can ownership of a resource be shared? Then use `std::shared_ptr`. In my opinion, it almost never makes sense to  use manual and explicit memory handling (or smart pointers) for what is essentially arrays or vectors.

Comment: On another couple of notes, when creating a [mcve] to show us, please try to avoid unrelated errors or problems. For example `make_unique<int[]> >` contains a `>` to many. And `std::unique_ptr<T>` is a distinct and incompatible type from `std::shared_ptr<T>` (`foo` uses `std::shared_ptr`, but you call it using a `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: Why do you use std::unique_ptr<int[]> pointer(new int[5]);  ? and not use std::unique_ptr<int*> pointer(new int[5]);

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude aha okay i am sorry for that. let me edit it.

Comment: @FarhadSarvari thank you good question.i am not expert of it and i am here to learn.  so you tell me the difference why i should use std::unique_ptr<int*> pointer and not usestd::unique_ptr<int[]> pointer?for me there is no difference but you can give me better explantion.

Comment: The `[]` version of `shared_ptr` doesn't let you dereference with `*`. I assume it's a design decision to discourage conflation of arrays and pointers. If you want a `shared_ptr` to an element, you can use the aliasing c'tor: `std::shared_ptr<int>(i, i.get() + index);` which has the lifetime from `i` but the poitner from `i.get() + index`. https://godbolt.org/z/7n9T7K

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i was just experimenting that can i cast unique_ ptr to shared_ptr?

Comment: No it's not possible. If it was, then it would take away the "uniqueness" of the pointer (the single ownership semantics).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Agree with you. that's what i also understood from this experiment.

Comment: thank you @ben . that's aliasing c'tor is something new to me and seems useful.

Comment: You can't cast from `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` because as @Someprogrammerdude says, it would defeat the purpose, but you can do `std::shared_ptr<T> sp = std::move(up);` where `up` is a `std::unique_ptr<T>`. Which means if you have a function, `f`, returning a `std::unique_ptr<T>`, you can do `std::shared_ptr<T> sp = f();`. At that point, there's no way to go back to a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @NileshSolanki because if you want use from make_unique for array you should just pass the size of array. You should use  auto pointer3 = make_unique<int[]> (5);

Comment: @NileshSolanki I just mentioned that unbounded array. It is possible to use size and for bounded array it is disabled.

Comment: Aha thank you @FarhadSarvari.that's worked with make_unique. i tried it before but because of (*i)++ is giving me error i thought it's also wrong with it.that's worked with make_unique.

Comment: Be aware, you typically want to use `std::vector<T>` or `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>`. There are places for `shared_ptr<T[]>`, but it it shouldn't be your go-to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `shared_ptr` stores an array, then (and only then) `shared_ptr::operator[]` provides access to individual elements of the stored array.

`shared_ptr::operator*` provides access to the stored object as a whole. It is defined for all types of stored objects. If that's an array, then that's the whole array.

That's a quite intentional departure from the standard C/C++ array/pointer semantics, where `*x` and `x[0]` are one and the same thing by definition. `shared_ptr` doesn't behave this way, because its designers didn't want it to behave this way.